# How to write a script to log in multiple server using for loop and ssh?

Tags: ssh, awk

I want to write a script using a for loop  and ssh, to log in several server. After logging in using awk command I want to get 7th column printed as output.

I tried the script below but couldn't worked out.

I created a list of IP's in `/tmp/list`.

```
for i in `cat /tmp/list`
do
echo $i
echo "***********"
ssh $i |grep tsm |awk -F : '{print $7, "\t"}'
echo
done
```

Comment: The 7th column of what? Do your remote servers display some sort of status info when you log in?

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107800/using-while-loop-to-ssh-to-multiple-servers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pssh](https://code.google.com/archive/p/parallel-ssh/) makes this much easier, but for your simple use case `ssh` will also work.

While what you have above could have worked, provided the server is set up to run a command and exit on login (which is somewhat unlikely) you probably meant something like this:

```
ssh $i <command> | grep tsm | ...
```

If you really need to check a login banner for `tsm`, try using the command `exit` to immediately return back from the ssh rather than starting an interactive shell:

```
ssh $i "exit" | grep tsm | ...
```