# Want to create a script to grep a particular word from a specific path of remote server

Tags: shell-script

I want to create a script wherein I can grep a particular word from a specific path of remote server and display that whole grep sentence in the output.

Currently, I have to take access to the target server, then to go in the particular path and then use the grep command.

```
 #!/usr/bin/ksh

clientID="00000" 

print -n "\nEnter the  ID (Enter ybr for ybr_ybrfndt): $1" 
read clientID
print "$clientID"

for HOST in $(cat qa_servers.txt ) ; 
do 
    ssh $HOST "uname -a" 
    cd /apps/WebSphere/NA70_TBA/config/cells/CellV70_TBA
    grep $clientID resources.xml; 
done
```

Comment: welcome to U&L, we are not a scripting services, what have you tried so far ? can you provide (by editing your question) some sample (environment , expected output) ?

Comment: #!/usr/bin/ksh

for server in "${qa_servers.txt[@]}"; 
{ ssh cacher@$server

cd /apps/WebSphere/NA70_TBA/config/cells/CellV70_TBA
untar archive

clientID="00000"

print -n "\nEnter the client ID: $1" 
read clientID
print "$clientID"

grep '$clientID' resources.xml
}

Comment: Put this information _in the question_, not in a comment.

Comment: Your code is nonsensical. The `for` loop does not have a `do` and you are using variables (some of which are arrays) that you never set.

Comment: how about this         #!/usr/bin/ksh
 
clientID="00000" 

print -n "\nEnter the  ID (Enter ybr for ybr_ybrfndt): $1" 
read clientID
print "$clientID"

for HOST in $(cat qa_servers.txt ) ; 
 do ssh $HOST "uname -a" 
 cd /apps/WebSphere/NA70_TBA/config/cells/CellV70_TBA
 grep $clientID resources.xml; 
done

Comment: But with this code I am unable to enter into the target server. I just want to get into the target server and want to get the output of below two commands from target server

Answer (score 1):

This script should work for your use case.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh 

print -n "\nEnter the ID (Enter ybr for ybr_ybrfndt):"
read clientID

while IFS= read -r host
do
    ssh -n $host "uname -a; grep $clientID /apps/WebSphere/NA70_TBA/config/cells/CellV70_TBA/resources.xml;"
done < qa_servers.txt
```

Comment: yes it's working...thanks...but what if i want the same for multiple servers

Comment: @user334028 There's a `while` loop here that reads from the 'qa_servers.txt' file, one line at a time. So the `ssh` command will be executed for each line in that file. Do you mean something else by 'multiple servers'?

Comment: I just meant that if in the text file i enter the next server name in next line. Will it work ?

Comment: @user334028 Yes, it will work. There are no destructive commands involved here, so feel free to experiment.

Comment: nope....it's not working for more than one server

Comment: @user334028 You'll need to show me your 'qa_servers.txt` file before I can comment on that.

Comment: the script has stopped working now. have you edited something in it ??

Comment: @user334028 Nope. You can see the edit timestamps on my answer - the last edit was 3 hours ago.

Comment: okie....but it's getting terminated after reading the client id

Comment: @user334028 There was a problem with SSH reading stdin earlier, which is why the multiple servers list did not work in your case. I've fixed it now by adding the `-n` parameter. You can find more details on that problem here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/107800/173368

Comment: #!/usr/bin/ksh 

print -n "\nEnter the ID (Enter ybr for ybr_ybrfndt):"
read clientID

The script is working only till here

Comment: @user334028 Do keep in mind that I cannot actually see your system, so any advice I can give would be limited. One thing to check is that the redirected file (qa_servers.txt) is not empty. Another thing you can do is to the run the script with `ksh -x` so that you see the debugging output.

Comment: Thanks. I am able to run the script as expected now. Thanks a ton

Can you help me with just a small doubt. Is it possible to put a while loop in else statement. If yes can you tell me the syntax for it ??

Comment: @user334028 Yes, you should be able to use a while loop inside an if-else block. There's nothing special about the syntax here, it's identical to a typical if-else. Also, if my answer has resolved your problem, you may mark it as accepted by clicking the 'tick' mark next to it.