# Bash Script: Loop through a file

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian, ssh

I have a file with some lines in it:

```
/snapshot/200
/snapshot/201
/snapshot/202
```

Now i'm trying to use each line with a while IFS loop to do certain actions with them.

```
while IFS=' ' read -r test || [ -n "${test}" ];
do
    if ssh root@$TARGET "[ ! -d $test ]"
    then
        echo "${test}"
    fi
done < $filelist
```

The problem here I only get one result and it's not looping through the whole file? The if statement should be correct, since there are no directories with these names.

If however i remove the entire if part and just use

```
echo "${test}"
```

the loop works.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107800/using-while-loop-to-ssh-to-multiple-servers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ssh` inherits the standard input stream from the `while` loop and will read your whole `$filelist` file, apart from its first line which is read by `read`.

To stop `ssh` from doing this, use `ssh -n`, or `ssh ... </dev/null`.

`ssh` works this way to to allow you to pass data via a simple redirection or pipe to the remote system, as in

```
ssh remote 'cat >remotefile' <localfile
```

See also "[Need help understanding shell command with pipes, redirections and remote connections](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/584686/)".

Comment: Thanks! Never imagined SSH is the culprit!