# Need help understanding shell command with pipes, redirections and remote connections

Tags: bash, terminal, pipe

I have some experience using the bash, but this command here which I saw in a tutorial caught me off guard:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh git@remote-server "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

I know what the command does. It takes the output of the file `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, then `ssh`s to a remote server, creates a new directory under user home called .ssh then creates a new file called `authorized_keys` and pours the contents of the `id_rsa.pub` into that file. What I couldn't figure out is, at which point contents of the `id_rsa.pub` file gets *injected* into the authorized keys file.

So, I know pipe (|) takes the output to its left and feeds it to the command to the right hand side of it. But normally we use cat command like this:

```
cat "content_to_be_added" >> file_to_be_appended
```

so, if I'm not mistaken, contents of `id_rsa.pub` should get injected right before >> in order for this to work. So, how does this function exactly and why?

By the way, please feel free to correct my terminology. I'd also appreciate if you can tell me if this operator here `>>` has a specific name.

Comment: This seems to be re-inventing `ssh-copy-id`.

Comment: @Panki Only on systems that provide that tool. It's not (yet) a part of the official OpenSSH distribution.

Comment: `>>` is a *redirection operator*. See for example [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command

```
cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

reads from standard input (since no filename was given to `cat` to read from) and appends to the named file. The `>>` redirection operator opens the target file for *appending*.  Using `>` in place of `>>` would have truncated (emptied) the target file before writing the data.

Where does the data on standard input of that remote `cat` command come from? The standard input stream is inherited by `cat` from the remote shell.  The remote shell inherits the standard input stream from `ssh`.  The standard input for `ssh` comes via the pipe from the local `cat` command, which reads the `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file.

---

The local `cat` is not needed in your pipeline:

```
ssh git@remote-server 'mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys' < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Note, however, that if `mkdir` does actually create a directory, that directory needs to have the correct permissions for `ssh` to work properly:

```
ssh git@remote-server 'mkdir -p ~/.ssh && chmod 700 ~/.ssh && cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys' < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Or, you may just choose to fail to append the data:

```
ssh git@remote-server 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys' < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, if I execute this: 

`cat "yeah" | ssh git@remote-server "echo"`, would I read "yeah" on my remote stdout?

Comment: `echo yeah | ssh user@remote-server cat` would do that - it's cat that reads from standard input, not echo.

Comment: @SercioSoydanov: `cat "yeah"` would output the content of the "yeah" file (if existing).

Comment: Ok guys thanks to you all.

Answer (score 0):

For `cat`, if no filename is given, it shall copy stdin to stdout.

The `>>` is called output redirection operator.

Simply `cat >> filename` will **append** data coming on the standard input to the file "filename".

In your example: `cat "content_to_be_added"` the "content_to_be_added" is not really a content, it is the name of the input file.