# Using ssh in a while read loop reading from stdin

Tags: busybox, ash

I have a shell function that returns a list of hostnames and IP addresses:

```
$ list_hosts
hostA 10.1.1.1
hostB 10.1.1.2
hostC 10.1.1.3
```

I want to get a different address for each host:

```
$ function list_ip6 {
  list_hosts | while read -r hostname ip ; do
    ip6=$(ssh ${ip} ip -o address list eth0 | awk '/scope global/ {print $4;}')
    echo "Host ${name} has IP6 ${ip}"
  done
}
```

This only prints out the IP6 for the first host returned by `list_hosts`:

```
$ list_ip6
Host hostA has IP6 fd57:9e3a:c90e:753f:d625:ccff:feb0:7984/128
```

The problem appears to be the command substitution on the second line; if I comment that out, it loops over all the hosts:

```
$ list_ip6
Host hostA has IP6
Host hostB has IP6
Host hostC has IP6
```

Does the process substitution somehow interfere with reading from the the output of `list_hosts`?

Is there a good way of doing this in the busybox `ash` shell?  In `bash` I would just read the lines into an array and loop over the array but of course that's not an option in ash.

Edit to add:

The problem seems to be specifically the `ssh` connection.  If I just print out the local IP6 for each host then it works correctly:

```
$ function list_ip6 {
  list_hosts | while read -r hostname ip ; do
    ip6=$(ip -o address list eth0 | awk '/scope global/ {print $4;}')
    echo "Host ${name} has IP6 ${ip}"
  done
}

$ list_ip6
Host hostA has IP6 fd57:9e3a:c90e:753f:d625:ccff:feb0:7931/128
Host hostB has IP6 fd57:9e3a:c90e:753f:d625:ccff:feb0:7931/128
Host hostC has IP6 fd57:9e3a:c90e:753f:d625:ccff:feb0:7931/128
```

The process substitution is okay, it's just that SSH somehow breaks out of the loop.

Comment: And also [Using while loop to ssh to multiple servers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/107800/170373)